# Travis build failing due to mocha not found in project subfolder

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, travis-ci

I have the following compilation error using Travis CI for my github project:

```
sh: 1: mocha: not found
```

My main project folder, "projectRoot", which corresponds to my github repo, contains the .travis.yml configuration file; it also contains several sub folders (one per application):

```
projectRoot
|-- app1
    |-- app1.js
    |-- package.json
    |--- node_modules
         |--- .bin
              |--- mocha
              |--- mocha.cmd
|-- app2
    |-- app2.js
    |-- package.json
    |--- node_modules
         |--- .bin
              |--- mocha
              |--- mocha.cmd
|-- app3
|-- ...
```

Each application has its own package.json and node_modules packages.

The package.json of app1 contains the following:

```
  "scripts": {
    "test": "mocha"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "chai": "^4.2.0",
    "mocha": "^5.2.0"
  },
```

And I get the following error when Travis CI tries to run the unit tests of app1:

```
$ npm test
> projectRoot@1.0.2 test /home/travis/build/username/projectRoot/app1
> mocha
sh: 1: mocha: not found
npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
```

I tried adding the following before_script to change the current directory to app1, then amending the PATH variable prior to starting the tests:

```
before_script:
  - echo "*** PRE BUILD SCRIPT ***"
  - cd ./app1
  - export PATH=$(pwd)/node_modules/.bin:$PATH
  - echo $PATH
  - echo "*************************"
```

After doing so, the "echo $PATH" line above shows in the travis logs that PATH contains the project folder:

```
$ echo $PATH
/home/travis/build/username/projectRoot/app1/node_modules/.bin:/home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/bin:/home/travis/......
```

But the error remains.

I also tried:

```
PATH=./node_modules/.bin:$PATH.
```

or changing the test script to use a relative path:

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "./node_modules/.bin/mocha"
 }
```

But the same error remains.

Any advise would be truly appreciated.

Many thanks for your help